# TextFormField, change icon and text colors

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the `labelText` and the `icon` colors of my `TextFormField` when it's highlighted. This is my code:

```
TextFormField(
            enabled: enable,
            controller: textEditingController,
            obscureText: obscureText,
            validator: validate,
            keyboardType: keyboardType,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide:
                    BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
              ),
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              enabledBorder: _checkBorder(),
              labelText: labelText,
              prefixIcon: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(distanceIconFromEdges),
                child: icon,
              ),
              hintText: hintText,
            ))
```

Comment: Wrap your `TextFormField` in `Theme` and change `accentColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `TextFormField` in `Theme` and change `accentColor`

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.red),
  child: TextFormField(...),
)
```